# Строчный курсор между <button> в блоке

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.
Есть блок:

```css
.service {
  &__btn:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  &__svg>* {
    transition: stroke .2s;
  }
  &__svg:hover>* {
    stroke: #b79163;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons__service service">
  <button class="service__btn">
                     <svg class="service__svg" width="22" height="23" viewBox="0 0 22 23" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <circle r="8.73651" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 12.7635 9.23651)" stroke="white" />
                        <line y1="-0.5" x2="9.05625" y2="-0.5" transform="matrix(-0.661466 0.749975 0.749975 0.661466 6.99014 16.1639)" stroke="white" />
                     </svg>
                  </button>
  <button class="service__btn">
                     <svg class="service__svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 25 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M3.47251 23.1939L1.23597 11.8781C1.11379 11.2599 1.58687 10.6842 2.21699 10.6842H22.7623C23.3992 10.6842 23.8738 11.2716 23.74 11.8942L21.309 23.21C21.21 23.6709 20.8026 24 20.3313 24H4.45354C3.976 24 3.56511 23.6623 3.47251 23.1939Z" stroke="white" />
                        <path d="M7.05249 13.1053C7.05249 -3.03509 17.9472 -3.03508 17.9472 13.1053" stroke="white" />
                     </svg>
                  </button>
  <button class="service__btn">
                     <svg class="service__svg" width="24" height="23" viewBox="0 0 24 23" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <circle cx="10.9297" cy="5.79614" r="5.29614" stroke="white" />
                        <path d="M22.535 21.5304C22.5626 21.7348 22.3962 21.9601 22.1018 21.9601H11.5509H0.947337C0.66028 21.9601 0.50522 21.7507 0.520952 21.5717C0.584401 20.8498 0.791981 20.1324 1.14315 19.4409C1.63256 18.4772 2.39269 17.5806 3.39044 16.8097C4.38826 16.0388 5.59932 15.4128 6.95544 14.9742C8.31129 14.5356 9.7796 14.2949 11.2731 14.2683C12.7665 14.2417 14.2504 14.4298 15.6363 14.82C17.0224 15.2102 18.2775 15.7932 19.33 16.5294C20.3825 17.2656 21.2064 18.1368 21.7638 19.0851C22.1515 19.7446 22.4177 20.663 22.535 21.5304Z" stroke="white" />
                     </svg>
                  </button>
</div>
```

Когда мышка попадает между кнопками, то меняется на курсор, как в текстовом редакторе.
Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу от этого избавиться?
Менял у кнопок display на inline-block, но ничего не вышло.

Comment: Приложите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @another_login добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
.service {
  cursor: default;
  &__btn {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Все теперь как надо!